# Hyper-V Server 2012 - Acquisition of genuine ticket failed

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

I have been using Hyper-V Server 2012 (the free, core edition) for a few months now, and every day, the server dutifully generates this error in the Application log:

```
HYPER2012   8208    Error   Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP  Application 1/18/2013 10:00:14 AM

Acquisition of genuine ticket failed (hr=0xC004C4A2) for template Id {67a81643-c828-3e62-341f-a5bd2a25048d}
```

It doesn't affect anything, but I sure wouldn't mind getting rid of it if I could.  Every day at 10AM, there it is, waiting for me in the event log.

In Server Manager, the server displays as "Activated" under the Windows Activation column.

Halp.

Edit: Also, I get this when I run slmgr /ato:

```
Activating Windows(R), ServerHyperCore edition
{guid-stuff} ...
Error: 0xC004C003 The activation server determined the specified product key is blocked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Microsoft licensing. If your license is legit then licensing technical support is free. Since you are using hyper-v server there should be no question.

Comment: Yeah... I suppose... it's just weird that Hyper-V Server would install with an error-generating license key... being *free* and all. Seems like Microsoft licensing support wouldn't want those extra phone calls.